# Presentation to Video conversion

Tags: video, conversion, presentation

I'd like to make several online language courses, and was thinking about incorporating video into a lecture.

I was looking for a way to convert presentations (PowerPoint or OpenOffice) directly to some video format, or, indirectly, maybe through Adobe Flash format.

Right now I'm on a Ubuntu.

Maybe there is some kind of tool, like FFmpeg style?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a Screen Capture program or Screen Cast program.  A quick Google search turned up gtk-recordMyDesktop as an option that should work for your purposes and appears to be built in to Ubuntu.  [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24742/record-screen-activity-in-ubuntu-with-recordmydesktop/) was the site I found that explained more detail on how it is used.  I personally have no experience working with Ubuntu, let alone screen capture on it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also came this conclusion. For reference, there is another one, called 'Kazam Screencaster'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "very" old question, but there is a pretty **simple** method to do this (and something that comes up surprisingly often). So if you landed here, I do hope you find this solution helpful.

1. Change the individual slides to pdf.
2. Turn the pdf to jpg
3. Turn the jpg's into a film.

To do this I have used unoconv, ghostscript, graphicsmagick and ffmpeg.

First: Update your system.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install unoconv gs graphicsmagick
```

Because ffmpeg is pretty complicated for beginners to install correctly, there is a page here that shows you:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Then the following console command will change the ppt into a pdf:

```
 unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt
```

The following command will turn the pdf into a series of images:

```
 pageNum=$(gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(presentation.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"); gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=$pageNum -sOutputFile=%09d.jpg -dJPEGQ=90 -r90 presentation.pdf -c quit
```

And finally turn the images into a video where every frame is 15 seconds long.

```
 ffmpeg -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f s16le -i /dev/zero -r 1/15 -f image2 -i %09d.jpg -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=fps=25" -shortest presentation.mp4
```

Of course if you are smart (and need to do this often) you'd turn it into a bash script. Good luck.

Comment: And for extra credit, you can use the browser to skip to the next slide. Here is a bit of info on that: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/how-to-make-a-video-presentation-with-the-possibility-to-go-to-the-next-or-the-p/12507#12507